# Using Join in Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this query in sql :-

```
Select
    * 
from
    ClassNote C 
    Join ClassSubMatRelation CSMR on C.ClassNoteID=CSMR.ClassNoteFK 
where
    CSMR.BoardFK = 1 
    and
    CSMR.SubjectFK in
        (
            select
                t.SubjectFK
            from
                ClassSubMatRelation t
            where
                t.BoardFK = 1
        ) 
    and
    CSMR.SubjectFK not in
        (
           select
                e.SubjectFK
            from
                ClassSubMatRelation e
            where
                e.BoardFK != 1
        ) 
    and
    CSMR.Status_Info = 1
    and
    CSMR.ClassNoteFK is not null
```

The query is working fine. But I guess I can use joins to make it simpler and faster. As you see I'm new to this so can't figure out how can I do this. I've tried other solutions bt they didn't work correctly.

My Table Schemas:-

```
ClassNote (
    ClassNoteID
    Heading
    ClassNoteDesc
    ClassNoteRefID
    Status_Info
)

ClassSubMatRelation (
    ClassSubMatRelationID
    BoardFK
    ClassFK
    SubjectFK
    MaterialFK
    ClassNoteFK
    ClassEbookFK
    ClassSPFK
    Status_Info
)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far using Joins?

Comment: Please provide the schemas for the tables ClassNote and ClassSubMatRelation.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu will show you shortly.

Comment: @Sphinx For ClassSubMatRelation :- ClassSubMatRelationID,
BoardFK,
ClassFK,
SubjectFK,
MaterialFK,
ClassNoteFK,
ClassEbookFK,
ClassSPFK,
Status_Info and For ClassNote  :- ClassNoteID,
Heading,
ClassNoteDesc,
ClassNoteRefID,
Status_Info

Comment: @Deepak You need to add your schema into the question instead of the comments.

Comment: @Sphinx Ok . Will do that now

Comment: @Sphinx Edited My question

Comment: I am struggling with the `IN/NOT IN`.  Seems like they net out to just a single join on `CSMR.SubjectFK = ClassSubMatRelation.SubjectFK` as long as they are not `NULL`

Comment: The `IN/NOT IN` clauses are mutually exclusive, there is no need for two of them.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve here is , I need to have all the SubjectFK which are in single BoardFK only. For Ex:- If I have Board1 and Board2. Board1 has Subject1 and Subject2, while Board2 has Subject1 and Subject3. Now If I'll pass ID Board1 then I should only get Subject2 not Subject1. Lemme know If I'm not clear.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does "ClassSubMatRelation" mean in real-world terms? What domain-entity or relation does it represent?

Comment: Joins can change the cardinality of the result. `IN` is basically an inner join if it's 1:1. `NOT IN` could be an outer join with filter moved to the join condition and a test for FK is null. Honestly what you have is probably better anyway.

Comment: @Dai It's a relation table I'm having for Board,Class,Subject,Material tables. I'm not good at naming tables. am I? :)

Comment: @shawnt00 Is it so? I've been trying to do this via joins for long.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* put some restrictions on the join to CSMR by moving some of the `WHERE` to the `JOIN`'s `ON` statement.
Like this:

```
Select * 
from ClassNote C 
Join ClassSubMatRelation CSMR 
  on C.ClassNoteID=CSMR.ClassNoteFK
  and CSMR.Status_Info=1 
  and CSMR.ClassNoteFK is not null
  and CSMR.BoardFK = 1

where CSMR.SubjectFK in (select t.SubjectFK from ClassSubMatRelation t where t.BoardFK=1) 
and CSMR.SubjectFK not in (select e.SubjectFK from ClassSubMatRelation e where e.BoardFK!=1)
```

but I don't think that is going to speed things up much. SQL Server optimizes pretty well... At least it's a little simpler to read.

EDIT- Now that I look at it, are those two IN statements even necessary? the IN is getting all BoardFK = 1 and the NOT IN is making sure you are getting nothing that isn't 1....
Since you are already explicitly specifying that BoardFK =  1 in the where, you shouldn't need those...    So, something like this:

```
Select * 
from ClassNote C 
Join ClassSubMatRelation CSMR 
  on C.ClassNoteID=CSMR.ClassNoteFK
  and CSMR.Status_Info=1 
  and CSMR.ClassNoteFK is not null
  and CSMR.BoardFK = 1
```

NOTE: doing it like this won't behave the same if you decide to change this to an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: You might have to `DISTINCT` if you do that. Depends on the cardinality

Comment: Thanks for your time Daniel. Is there any way out I can remove the 2 selects and execute my query using joins?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
Select
    * 
from
    ClassNote C 
    Join ClassSubMatRelation CSMR on C.ClassNoteID=CSMR.ClassNoteFK AND 
        CSMR.BoardFK = 1  
    AND 
        CSMR.Status_Info = 1
    AND  
        CSMR.ClassNoteFK is not null
    Join ClassSubMatRelation t on t.SubjectFK = CSMR.SubjectFK AND t.BoardFK = 1
    LEFT JOIN ClassSubMatRelation e ON e.SubjectFK AND e.BoardFK != 1 AND e.SubjectFK IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your second `CSMR.SubjectFK` clause is redundant: the first one matches only rows where `t.BoardFK = 1` while the second clause excludes rows where `t.BoardFK != 1`, but they will have already been excluded by the first clause, making it entirely superfluous. They can both be replaced with a single `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    ClassNote.*
FROM
    ClassNote
    INNER JOIN ClassSubMatRelation AS csmr ON ClassNote.ClassNoteId = csmr.ClassNoteFK
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassSubMatRelation AS subject ON csmr.SubjectFK = subject.SubjectFK
WHERE
    csmr.BoardFK = 1
    AND
    subject.SubjectFK = 1
    AND
    csmr.Status_Info = 1
```

Comment: For the redundant you decribed, considering this scenarios: 1: t.BoardFK=1 has one record with SubjectFK=CSMR.SubjectFK 2: t.BoardFK!=1 has one record with SubjectFK=CSMR.Subject. If SubjectFK is unique, it will be the redundant. But 'CSMR.BoardFK = 1' and     'CSMR.SubjectFK in
        (
            select
                t.SubjectFK
            from
                ClassSubMatRelation t
            where
                t.BoardFK = 1
        ) ' is the redundant.